# Why isn't the volatility version of the Nelson-Siegel model in the same shape as the original yield model?

Tags: yield-curve, term-structure

If we compare the form of the original model:
https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/3180059/mod_resource/content/0/Nelson%2C%20Siegel%20%281987%29%20-%20Parsimonious%20Modeling%20of%20Yield%20Curves.pdf

To the form of the model developed in this paper (which was 'inspired' by the original NS):
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/264717516_The_Nelson-Siegel_Model_of_the_Term_Structure_of_Option_Implied_Volatility_and_Volatility_Components

You can see that in the original paper the power of `e` is `-tte/lambda` (negative time to expiration divided by the decay parameter). However in the second paper the power of `e` is `-tte * lambda` (negative time to expiration TIMES the decay parameter). What is the reason behind that? I've tried to read through the papers to find the reason behind that but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: They are equivalent as $\lambda\mapsto 1/\lambda$ is bijective when $\lambda\ne 0$.